# Word Fast Counting

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, optimization, count

I'm implementing a word count feature for my ASP.NET server, and I was wondering what would be the fastest method of doing so, as I'm not sure using a simple

```
text.AsParallel().Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace);
```

is the fastest possible method. Since this feature might be used quite a bit on relatively long walls of text, I want it to be as fast as possible, even if it means using unsafe methods.

Edit: Some benchmarking with Rufus L's code as well as my own unsafe method:

```
public static unsafe int CountWords(string s)
    {
        int count = 0;
        fixed (char* ps = s)
        {
            int len = s.Length;
            char* pc = ps;
            while (len-- > 0)
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(*pc++))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

> Split(null): 681979 words in 415867 ticks.
>
> Count(WhiteSpace): 681978 words in 147860 ticks.
>
> AsParallel: 681978 words in 401077 ticks.
>
> Unsafe: 681978 words in 98139 ticks.

I'm still open to any better ideas :)

EDIT2:

Rewrote the function, taking care of multiple white spaces too:

```
public static unsafe int CountWords(string s)
    {
        int count = 0;
        fixed (char* ps = s)
        {
            int len = s.Length;
            bool inWord = false;
            char* pc = ps;
            while (len-- > 0)
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(*pc++))
                {
                    if (!inWord)
                    {
                        inWord = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (inWord)
                    {
                        inWord = false;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (len == 0)
                {
                    if (inWord)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

> Split(null): 681979 words in 517055 ticks.
>
> Count(WhiteSpace): 681978 words in 148952 ticks.
>
> AsParallel: 681978 words in 410289 ticks.
>
> Unsafe: 660000 words in 114833 ticks.

Comment: two points 1) benchmark first. it is linear and cheap, meaning very-very fast even on "long walls of text" 2) AsParallel doesn't make much sense on server-side apps.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some benchmarking, the following unsage code yielded the fastest result in any case with 500+ words:

```
public static unsafe int CountWords(string s)
{
    int count = 0;
    fixed (char* ps = s)
    {
        int len = s.Length;
        bool inWord = false;
        char* pc = ps;
        while (len-- > 0)
        {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(*pc++))
            {
                if (!inWord)
                {
                    inWord = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (inWord)
                {
                    inWord = false;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (len == 0)
            {
                if (inWord)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to my tests, this is much faster, by a factor of 4 (but see the update below for different results):

```
wordCount = text.Split(null).Length;
```

Here's the test, in case you want to try it out. Note that adding `AsParallel()` slows the process down on my machine, due to the cost of task switching:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var text = File.ReadAllText("d:\\public\\temp\\temp.txt");
    int wordCount;
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    wordCount = text.Split(null).Length;
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Split(null): {0} words in {1} ticks.", wordCount, 
        sw.ElapsedTicks);

    sw.Restart();
    wordCount = text.Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace);
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Count(WhiteSpace): {0} words in {1} ticks.", wordCount, 
        sw.ElapsedTicks);

    sw.Restart();
    wordCount = text.AsParallel().Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace);
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("AsParallel: {0} words in {1} ticks.", wordCount, 
        sw.ElapsedTicks);
}
```

Output:

> Split(null): 964 words in 629 ticks.
>
> Count(WhiteSpace): 963 words in 2377 ticks.
>
> AsParallel: 963 words in 208983 ticks.

**Update**

After making the string MUCH longer (OP mentioned 100's of 1000's of words), the results became much more similar, and the `Count(WhiteSpace)` method became faster than the `Split(null)` method:

Code change:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("d:\\public\\temp\\temp.txt");
var textToSearch = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) textToSearch.Append(text);
text = textToSearch.ToString();
```

Output:

> Split(null): 481501 words in 185135 ticks.
>
> Count(WhiteSpace): 481500 words in 101373 ticks.
>
> AsParallel: 481500 words in 336117 ticks.

Comment: Except it creates heaps of objects. In my case, it could mean hundreds of thousands of objects >_>

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking for the fastest, not the most memory efficient...

Comment: Thats the problem with answering these off-topic performance questions.

Comment: @Dracor I updated my code to parse close to 500,000 words, and that changed the results a little, where the `Count(WhiteSpace)` overtook the `Split(null)`. Memory was not an issue on my machine (I have 30 GB). I guess you will just have to test on your server!

Comment: @RufusL thanks, it's served as a good starting point and also used it for later benchmark comparisons ^^

Answer (score 0):

Answering your ask, the méthod AsParallel() is very fast. But exists more options, by e.g.:

**Using Regex:**

```
string input = "text text text text";
string pattern = "(-)";

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);    // Split on hyphens
Console.WriteLine("Words: {0}", substrings.count());
```

But I reiterate, the AsParallel () method is very fast. You can do a proof of concept, to find out which is better. Place a stopwatch () at the beginning and another at the end of code and compare the AsParallel runtime () with the regex, so will have a more 'exact' answer.

## Update

**Using Parallel.For:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = @"text text text text text text text text text text ";
            int count = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Generating words, wait...");
            Parallel.For(0, 100000, i =>
            {
                text += @"text text text text text text text text text text ";
            });


            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            Parallel.For(0, text.Length, i =>
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i]))
                    count++;
            });
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Words: {0} in {1} ticks", count, sw.ElapsedTicks);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

**Results:**

[image]

> PS: Note that the Parallel.For used is not managed

Comment: In my testing, AsParallel was much slower for this particular problem. I think it was spending too much time task switching for operations that were not compute intensive.

Comment: What quantity "~" of words you can proccess?